# T-SQL Operators LIKE need help

Tags: sql, linq, search, sql-like

i would like to search in DB

input string is **"oxoşil"**

1. o -> [o-ö]
2. x -> [x-ks]
3. ş -> [s-ş]
4. ş -> [ş-sh]

i need to search all of these cominations.
Needed finally search criteria is **[o-ö][x-ks][o-ö][ş-s-sh][i-ı]l**

is there any way to to this with t-sql like operator? or in linq?

Answer (score 3):

I would try coercing the collation to accent-insensitive.Of course, choose an appropriate one for you rather than latin/general

```
WHERE
    myCol COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI LIKE '%oxoşil%' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI
```

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. Utilize the capabilities of the underlying system instead of doing permutations on the query.

Answer (score 0):

One efficient way to do this is use a CLR Stored Procedure:

[Regular Expressions Make Pattern Matching And Data Extraction Easier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

See also: [TSQL Regular Expression Workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/)